# SQL query order by 2 fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
User | Score | Verified
1    | 1     | false
2    | 2     | false
3    | 2     | true
4    | 3     | false
```

Assume i have the following data, what im trying to achive is order as :

i want to get  1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4
I want to order first by score but also if someone is verified i need it first within the score then i move to next score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you just want two columns in the `order by`:

```
order by score, verified desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following should do the trick

```
order by score, verified
```